# React.js, Modal Login, Register

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I seek to make a condition, as long as Login is true, Registration false, and the same in reverse, While Registration true, Login false, Currently with the code I have the modals on the screen overlap

```
const [showModalLog, setShowModalLog] = useState (true);

    const openModalLog = () => {
        setShowModalLog(prev => !prev)
    };

const [showModalReg, setShowModalReg] = useState (false);

    const openModalReg = () => {
        setShowModalReg(prev => !prev)
    };
  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <div className="text-center m-3">
            <button className="btn btn-link" type="button" onClick={openModalLog}>inicio</button>
            <ModalLog showModalLog={showModalLog} setShowModalLog={setShowModalLog}/>
        </div>
        <div className="text-center m-3">
            <button className="btn btn-dark" type="button" onClick={openModalReg}>registro</button>
            <ModalReg showModalReg={showModalReg} setShowModalReg={setShowModalReg}/>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

thanks, code like this

```
    const openModalLog = () => {
        setShowModalReg(false)
        setShowModalLog(prev => !prev)
    };

    const openModalReg = () => {
        setShowModalLog(false)
        setShowModalReg(prev => !prev)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable one modal after enabling the other.

```
const openModalLog = () => {
        setShowModalReg(false)
        setShowModalLog(true)
    };
const openModalReg = () => {
        setShowModalReg(true)
        setShowModalLog(false)
    };
```